# Change class on tag

Tags: jquery, class, onclick

I would like to change a tag class on click.

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9u8Nc/

Got this HTML code:

```
<ul class="tags">
  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tag">Aventure</a>
    <div class="user-info">
      <p><b>Aventure</b> <br>
        + 2.300 activités</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tag">Famille</a>
    <div class="user-info">
      <p><b>Famille</b> <br>
        + 1.500 activités</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tag">Gourmet</a>
    <div class="user-info">
      <p><b>Gourmet</b> <br>
        + 500 activités</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a  I want the style change.

When I click again on it, I would like the style back.

Try this but it do not work.

```
$('.tag').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function :

```
$('.tag').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

When you click, it sets the class if it isn't set, or remove it if it's set.

In your css, replace

```
.tag .active
```

with

```
.tag.active
```

as `.tag .active` doesn't match an element with both classes but an element with class `active` in another element of class `tag`.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6PADy/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fn4U/)**

```
$('.tag').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```